# GitHub SSH troubles.... added the key... still doesn't work

Tags: github, push

Steps I did so far...

1. `sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "lock_ed_on@yahoo.com"`

- to generate keys

2. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

- to add keys to terminal

3. `cat /home/mink/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

- to copy the public key to Github

4. then I follow the Github instructions...

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
```

5. I get greeted with this message...

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

6. So I configure the user details [I thought I didn't need to do this because of the key setup????] And i continue with GitHub instructions

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:navyblueyes/template-test.git
git push -u origin master
```

7. Right after the push... I get greeted with this...

```
mink@DESKTOP-ALARD0U:/mnt/c/Users/Micha/.LocalCode/js-exercises/--templat$ git push -u origin master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I configure the user details [I thought I didn't need to do this because of the key setup????]

This (user.name/user.email) has nothing to do with remote repository hosting service **authentication** (which is why the SSH key is used for).
It is for local commits *authorship*.

Second, ping github.com: if it fails, that would mean a DNS resolution error.
If not, try, for testing, accessing the repository using HTTPS

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/navyblueyes/template-test.git
```

Try the same using SSH:

```
git -c 'core.sshCommand="ssh -v"' ls-remote https://github.com/navyblueyes/template-test.git
```

That last command will show you if your key is actually used.

Comment: `git ls-remote https://github.com/navyblueyes/template-test.git ` did the trick... thanks!!!